# Python -Requests -BS4 and scraping JS websites (ajax)

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Trying to scrape

https://online.transport.wa.gov.au/webExternal/registration/;jsessionid=f5niZvGzB71vhrxMujeQPc2lxEWUqj5nc_fuXDvU9ZvvmTEcncK7!1976798565!-891443374?0

and return my Rego details.

I am not getting any information returned. In the HTML text I can see the plate field is completed with my Rego.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://online.transport.wa.gov.au/webExternal/registration/page'


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 '
                  'Safari/537.36 Edg/107.0.1418.62',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://online.transport.wa.gov.au/webExternal/registration/;jsessionid=_4ndF3LkVxrzXCIH58W_'
               'dGyYg3zAXOpnScRtW2kndXAICNK2kUBx!-1720409949!-1658794803?0',
    'Host': 'online.transport.wa.gov.au',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/'
              'signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=70Pb5udz8enjqPcRk4OjOODjfORHr82eUe90pPSpitM83k2EWbRh!-1720409949!-1658794803; TS012ba7f5=0'
              '1becb1e5b6b9eda0a43a7a09fe67c8e8d893f7792d1d8270a95b4267bb1b1754adc3fc326aa6104de47ae36b87d71d4c1afa8f1'
              '73d2583279ddc291f0caef515f0f85c8ed',
    'sec-ch-ua': 'Microsoft Edge";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': 'windows',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'
}


data= {"plate": "1hdv242"}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

print(r.headers)
print(soup)
```

This is the code I am using at the moment; I have tried both POST and GET and still no results.

Can someone please advise on what the problem is, or on the things i need to read up on to be able to complete this.

Comment: Less complex solution in this case would be Selenium. Also, you asked the same question a couple of days ago.

Comment: Yes, I am not wanting to use Selenium as it is not compatible with iPhone. Yes, I did ask the same question but this one probably has better detail and information. Thanks for comments

Comment: @drunknmonkie you don't need to use `selenium`, Check below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently my answer is through iPad, but anyway that site can be solved via single request if you reversed the `JS` function, but i don't have time to do that for now.

Below is a solution using `requests`

```py
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0",
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        r1 = req.get(url)
        nurl = r1.url + "-1.IBehaviorListener.1-layout-layout_body-registrationRequestForm-searchButton="
        data = {
            "id3_hf_0": "",
            "plate": "1hdv242",
            "searchButton": 1
        }
        req.headers.update({
            'Wicket-Ajax': 'true',
            'Wicket-Ajax-BaseURL': '.'
        })
        r = req.post(nurl, data=data)
        match = url + re.search('(wicket.*?)]', r.text).group(1)
        r = req.get(match)
        df = pd.read_html(r.content, attrs={'class': 'registrationTable'})[0]
        print(df.T)


main('https://online.transport.wa.gov.au/webExternal/registration/')
```

Output:

```
              0     1      2     3       4                                5
0  Plate Number  Make  Model  Year  Colour  This vehicle licence expires on
1       1HDV242   KIA    RIO  2020   BLACK                       12/02/2023
```

Comment: Thanks αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη! you're a star. This was frustrating me and looking at your code I was well off from getting it right.

I don't suppose if you have some time, you could explain how the parts work and how you identified what parts of the URL to use.

Code works great and I am enjoying playing around with it. - Even a link to where I can learn more about scraping sites like this would be awesome